# How can increase the terminal's window size when connecting to a docker through PuTTY+SSH?

Tags: docker, putty

I have a docker container running on a Ubuntu server, which I connect to from a computer running Microsoft Windows. To connect to the docker container, I:

1. SSH into the Ubuntu server through PuTTY.
2. I run `command docker exec -it CONTAINER_NAME /bin/bash`

Once in the docker container, some programs such as nano, top or ncdu only uses a very small window size, e.g.:

[image]

[image]

How can increase the terminal's window size when connecting to a docker through PuTTY+SSH? I want to increase the number of visible rows and columns.

Comment: Regarding the close vote as "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. ", it seems that Docker qualifies as a tool used primarily for programming given the questions I see on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker